# Count Number of Records that Existed on a Date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, reporting

I'm trying to count the distinct number of records that fall within a time period, grouped/summed by day.

In this example, there are customer service tickets opened on a certain date, then closed on a later date. I'm trying to find out, for each day, how many tickets were open (said otherwise, the `closed status` is in the future relative to that date) at any point in time. Here is the query I am working with in MySQL:

```
SELECT `cal`.`dt`,
   COUNT(DISTINCT `sub_query`.`id`)
FROM `calendar_table` AS `cal`
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT `inc`.`id`,
      `inc`.`created_at`,
      `inc_stat`.`updated_at`
   FROM `incidents` AS `inc`
   JOIN `incident_statuses` AS `inc_stat` ON `inc_stat`.`incident_id` = 
`inc`.`id`
   WHERE `inc_stat`.`status` LIKE 'Closed') AS `sub_query` ON (`sub_query`.`created_at` >= `cal`.`dt` AND `sub_query`.`updated_at` <= `cal`.`dt`)

 WHERE `cal`.`dt` >= '2017-01-01'
 AND `cal`.`dt` <= NOW()
 GROUP BY `cal`.`dt`
```

The calendar table is simply a 'helper' table with properly formatted dates from 2010-2020.

**Sample calendar_table cal Data**

```
id       dt
1        2017-01-01
2        2017-01-02
3        2017-01-03
...      ...
```

**Sample incidents inc Data**

```
id     created_at
1      2017-01-01 08:45:01
1      2017-01-01 08:55:01
...    ...
```

**Sample incident_statuses inc_stat Data**

```
id        incident_id      status         updated_at
1         1                Closed         2017-01-02
2         2                Closed         2017-01-04
...       ...              ...            ...
```

The subquery is properly generating data in this format:

```
id         created_at         updated_at
1          2017-01-01         2017-01-02
2          2017-01-01         2017-01-04
3          2017-01-04         2017-01-05
```

My desired output would be this:

```
dt                    count(distinct `subquery`.`id`)
2017-01-01            2            
2017-01-02            2
2017-01-03            1
2017-01-04            3
2017-01-05            1
```

I realize this would be a lot simpler in a programming language with a FOR loop, but does anyone have guidance on how to do this only with SQL?

Comment: can you show sample data from the input tables as well?

Comment: Certainly - please see updated answer with greater detail. its a simple many to one relationship, where there can be many incident_statuses for one incident. I am interested in the 'Closed' status, and the day on which that Closed status was last updated

Comment: @CDD You changed your question, I didn't know...

Comment: @aendeerei sorry I've just been adding more detail. The core question and base SQL query are still the same.

Comment: @CDD No problem.

Comment: @CDD If you don't use "%" in `LIKE` at all, then use "=" not `LIKE`.

Comment: @CDD An advice: try always to use databases in order to accomplish db specific tasks. Programming languages should help as second option, if you can't use db properly

Comment: @CDD I reedited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what database you are using but I think you just need something the equivalent of:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,inc.created_at), COUNT(*)
  FROM incidents inc
 WHERE inc.created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND NOW()
 GROUP BY CONVERT(date,inc.created_at)
 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - this does get me the number of incidents opened by day, and I can do the inverse to find the number Closed by day, but I'm still having trouble merging those to find the number of incidents open on any given date. Also I edited the question to reflect that I'm using MySQL - small change to your query was reversing the CONVERT() parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    cal.dt
    , COUNT(IFNULL(inc_stat.id, 0)) as cntIncStat
FROM calendar_table AS cal
LEFT JOIN incidents AS inc ON inc.created_at = cal.dt
LEFT JOIN incident_statuses AS inc_stat ON inc_stat.incident_id = inc.id
GROUP BY cal.dt
HAVING
    inc_stat.status = 'Closed'
    AND cal.dt >= '2017-01-01'
    AND cal.dt <= NOW()
;
```

Comment: @CDD Changed `COUNT` to display `0` if `sub_query.id` is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks - however I am still getting a result of one row for each day between 2017-01-01 and today, with a null/zero count, as I did with my original query. I also tried changing the AND to an OR in line 15 and the result was the same.

Comment: @CDD You want for each day ONE record, showing the count (>=0) of `incident_statuses`, isn't it?!